# How can I show this ratio is $\geq 1$ for intervals of $X$, $Y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, roots

I come here from a substantial application in statistics where I have reason to belive that the following ratio (function) is

$$f(X,Y)=\frac{1}{(2XY^2-X^2Y^2+X^2-2X+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \ge 1$$

for $X,Y \in [0,1]$. How should I go about showing this? Maybe somebody can brush up my maths.

Extension: the function above is a simplification for $Z=1$ in

$$g(X,Y,Z)=\frac{((1-X)Z^2+X)}{Z(2Z^2Y^2(X-X^2)+Z^2(X^2-2X+1)+Y^2X^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \ge 1$$

where now $X,Y,Z \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I'd try plugging the function into wolframalpha first and maximize it... see what you get.  You can also give X and Y ranges (if they are not allowed to be all reals).  If wolframalpha agrees that it is bigger than 1, it may give you some insight as to why, if it is false, you should know right away.

Comment: @TravisJ Query to Wolframalpha results in nice plots, but where can I see the minimum over the range of values of X and Y in the [0,1] interval there?

Comment: The syntax is something like: maximize( {1/(2*x*y^2-...), x, y}, {x>=0, x<=1, y>=0, y<=1}).  You specify the function, what the variables are (x and y) and the range.  You can leave off the range part if you want.

Comment: Just an observation: asking if that ratio if $\geq1$ is the same as asking the denominator is $\leq1$. You can solve that one by 'hand' and get that it is true for every value of $X$ and $Y$ in the range $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2XY^2-X^2 Y^2+X^2-2X+1 = 1-X(2-X)(1-Y^2)\leq 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, that's plausible. Do you have any idea how to approach the exension?